# Refresh Token No getting during Authentication MSAL ANDROID Azure AD B2C

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c, android-studio-3.0, azure-ad-msal

I have integrated `Azure AD B2C` on my android App using `MSAL`, signin and signUp are working as expected. `access token` is only received once the authentication is success. No `refresh Token` is received  once the authentication is success.   i'm using the scope value  - `https://icorg.onmicrosoft.com/ffc-60c4234-bf7aff196847/offline_access` .  what will be the reason for not having the `Refresh Token` ??

Comment: Try to specify the scope with `offline_access` instead of `https://icorg.onmicrosoft.com/ffc-60c4234-bf7aff196847/offline_access`.

Comment: @JoyWang - i tried with that, now i'm not able to authenticate during signIn.

Comment: Are you requesting the token with your own api? If so, try to use space to separate them, like `https://icorg.onmicrosoft.com/ffc-60c4234-bf7aff196847/api/read offline_access`.

Comment: @joy Wang - i'm using MSAL library, so once the authentication is successfull,  azure libraray is returning a callback with `AccessToken`. but no `refresh token` is received.

Comment: Seems the library does not expose the refresh token - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/202#issuecomment-516602832

Answer (score 0):

MSAL doesn’t expose the refresh token. Use a network trace and you’ll see it in the response as long as the scope contained offline_access, which it will by default if you supply a scope corresponding to your resource.

Comment: so once the access token is expired, i was calling the `mSingleAccountApp.acquireTokenSilentAsync(getScopes( ), maccount.authority, getAuthSilentCallback( )); ` , so on the callbackof this method i'm getting an error  `messagecom.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $` how can i manage once the access token is expired in` MSAL azure AD B2C`?

Comment: Based on the GitHub issues, your issue is that the wrong parameter are being passed into the silent token method. Resulting in a html page being sent in the response rather than the JSON object. Detail your code around what the MSAL config is and what params you pass into acquireTokenSilent. A network trace would also help.

Comment: `mSingleAccountApp.acquireTokenSilentAsync(getScopes( ), maccount.authority, getAuthSilentCallback( ));` is working if the `token` is not expired. but if the `access token` is expired, it is throwing out the above mentioned error.

Comment: scope value is - `https://iocrg.onmicrosoft.com/ffcc-e64c-43b-aeed-bf7f196847/user.offline_access` authority value is `https://ibpocrg.b2clogin.com/54a1-b7b-488-9e03-36a891c19/v2.0/`. These are values passed when calling `acquireTokenSilentAsync`.

Comment: Your authority should contain a b2c policyId.

Comment: what should be policyId given, once the access token is expired?? Before Access token gets expired that  `acquireTokenSilentAsync` call was working properly. This error throws out only when `access` token get expired.